# simulating rolling two dice

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate rolling two dice. I used:

```
d2 <- sample(1:6, 10^6, replace = T) + sample(1:6, 10^6, replace = T)
```

and get the expected result. I also tried

```
s2d <- c()
for (i in 1:6) { 
  for (j in 1:6){ 
    s2d <- c(s2d, (i+j)) 
  } 
}
d2 <- sample(s2d, 10^6, replace=T)
```

and that works too,  but these feel a bit "brute force." Is there an easier,  more elegant way to do it?

In more general terms, is there a function that takes 2 (or more) independent events and does operations on them (addition, multiplication)?

Comment: How does the first solution seem brute force or inelegant? It's a 1 line solution. Is your issue that you can't roll an arbitrary # of dice?

Comment: The first solution is simple enough, but I was wondering if there is a function that takes two independent events and does addition (or, even,  multiplication for chains of conditional probabilities).

Comment: Note that the probability function of the result of adding the *value* of two random discrete variables isn't a sum, but the convolution of the probability functions. Were you after ways to do convolution? The second thing, where you multiply *probabilities*, not *values* is entirely a different kind of thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your issue is that you can't roll any arbitrary number of dice, something like:

```
rowSums(replicate(2, sample(6, 10^6, replace=T)))
```

Would be more flexible.

Comment: Thank you, this allows an arbitrary number of dice.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with David that nothing seems particularly wrong with your first option. Another way to go might be this, if you're really just after the sum of the two dice:

```
sample(2:12,size = 100,replace = TRUE, prob = table(outer(1:6,1:6,"+")) / 36)
```

Comment: Note to self: Must remember this one: ``outer(1:6,1:6,"+")``  :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a `dice` function in the TeachingDemos package that simulates the rolling of dice (and there is even an option to plot the results, but 1000 rolls would not make a meaningful plot).  This may seem a little less brute force, but internally it does similar to what has already been posted.  You can use apply or related functions to do things like sum across the columns of the return.