# Using the sample function

Tags: r

I want to simulate rolling the die using the sample function as shown below but my sample function does not work

```
n <- 6^48 - where n is the total outcomes for tossing two dice 24 times

sample(n, 2, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
```

Comment: What is meant by "does not work"? An error, if so what does it say, or an unexpected result? I suspect that 6^48 is not the number you want.

Comment: I believe that you want `sample(6, 48,replace = TRUE)`

Comment: 6^48 is greater than the largest integer that R can represent accurately

Comment: Related: [simulating two rolling dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820203/simulating-rolling-two-dice)

Answer (score 0):

The code below rolls a die 24 times. If two dice, you may repeat the execution.

```
sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),24,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL)
```